# How to append table in SQL using R?

Tags: sql, r, odbc, dbi, dbplyr

I am now using `odbc`/`dbplyr` R packages to control database. Though I know I could use the function `union` to bind two tables by row, I don't know how to append one table to another without loading the data into the local memory. Is there any solutions?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I approach this using a combination of dbplyr and DBI packages.

The idea is to insert a table query into an insert statement. The insert statement can then be executed on the database:

```r
append_database_table <- function(db_connection, db, schema, tbl_name, table_to_append) {

  query <- glue::glue("INSERT INTO {db}.{schema}.{tbl_name}\n{dbplyr::sql_render(table_to_append)}")

  # execute
  DBI::dbExecute(db_connection, as.character(query))
}
```

Notes:

- This all assumes that the table you wish to append to already exists in the database. Different syntax is needed if you are creating a new table.
- `dbplyr::sql_render` returns the query that defines the input table
- `query` is a text string of valid database code
- I am using SQL Server syntax. You may need to adjust this if you are using a different flavor of SQL.
- The above is a minimal example, the full function I use for this contains additional checks and ensures column names are correct. You can find it [here](https://github.com/simon-anasta/dbplyr_helpers/blob/master/dbplyr_helper_functions.R) along with the other support functions I use for dbplyr work.

This approach works even if your input table has some processing. Consider the following example:

```r
prepared_table = remote_table %>%
  filter(!is.na(col1)) %>%
  group_by(col1) %>%
  summarise(col2sum = sum(col2))

show_query(prepared_table)
```

This will return SQL code equivalent to:

```sql
SELECT col1, SUM(col2) AS col2sum
FROM remote_table
WHERE col1 IS NOT NULL
```

Appending this using:

```r
append_database_table(db_connection, "db", "my_schema", "existing_table", prepared_table)
```

Will create the following SQL query and execute it on the database:

```sql
INSERT INTO db.my_schema.existing_table
SELECT col1, SUM(col2) AS col2sum
FROM remote_table
WHERE col1 IS NOT NULL
```